# ExtJS get class name

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a listener which should change the class on mouseover event.

```
listeners: {
    mouseover: function() {
        this.removeCls(?); //get existing class name
        this.addCls('CAButtonHover');
    },
}
```

How can I get the existing class name and replace it with a new one?
I use ExtJS 6.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no need to have a reference to the existing classes and replace them all with the `CAButtonHover` class, you can use the [setCls](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.dom.Element.html#method-setCls) method.

```
this.setCls('CAButtonHover');
```

But this is not how a hover class is usually implemented. You add the class **alongside existing classes** on `mouseover` and remove it on `mouseleave`. Just make sure you have a higher CSS specificity on the hover class selector so that the hover rules get applied.